# Know any fallen angels?

Tags: mythology

Not a movie character  or a novel's protagonist, but from mythology, do you know any fallen angel and why did the angel *fell*? The only one I know is *Lucifer*

Note:

I have went through a list provided in wikipedia, but I couldn't get/understand the full background story on them! Lucifer however was much easier to research for me. Need just few names but the story of the angel should be described,I am all eyes for references too!

Comment: Let me see if we can refine your question. You want to know if there were other named Angels besides Lucifer who fell from Heaven in mythology? The problem with this is it may end up a list, which are generally frowned upon here. Let's see what the moderators think...

Comment: Are you looking for a specific mythos? Answers may vary depending on whether you have Judaism or Christianity in mind, not to mention Islam. Even leaving Abrahamic religions aside, I'm sure there are numerous legends of angelic or near-divine beings that fell from grace.

Comment: @Yawus nope, any type of mythology will do, I have only looked into christian mythology so far. But it HAS to be an Angel who  became fallen with no repentance!

Comment: @Thaddeus, yes that is exactly what I want to know. yea hopefully the question can meet it's purpose with no problems

Comment: I happen to have a reference book in front of me called Angels A-Z and if no moderator zaps the question, I am sure we can come up with something for you...

Comment: @Thaddeus Yes that will be helpful! Thanks

Comment: Look up the book of Enoch.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azazel

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book_of_Enoch#Description

> The first section of the book depicts the interaction of the fallen angels with mankind; Sêmîazâz compels the other 199 fallen angels to take human wives to "beget us children".

> And Semjâzâ, who was their leader, said unto them: 'I fear ye will not indeed agree to do this deed, and I alone shall have to pay the penalty of a great sin.' And they all answered him and said: 'Let us all swear an oath, and all bind ourselves by mutual imprecations not to abandon this plan but to do this thing.'. Then sware they all together and bound themselves by mutual imprecations upon it. And they were in all two hundred; who descended in the days of Jared on the summit of Mount Hermon, and they called it Mount Hermon, because they had sworn and bound themselves by mutual imprecations upon it.

The names of the leaders are given as "Samyaza (Shemyazaz), their leader, Araqiel, Râmêêl, Kokabiel, Tamiel, Ramiel, Dânêl, Chazaqiel, Baraqiel, Asael, Armaros, Batariel, Bezaliel, Ananiel, Zaqiel, Shamsiel, Satariel, Turiel, Yomiel, Sariel."

Comment: Thanks @JamesChristopher , I have started looking into book of Enoch!